# Vue remaining items in data value if it is array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have Vue application which has a array of errors in data object. Problem is that I can not set errors array to empty []. I try to set it in the begining of validation function but previous items still remain there. This is the code:

```
<div v-if="uploadErrors && uploadErrors.length" class="has-text-danger">
     <div v-for="(error, index) in uploadErrors" :key="index" class="is-size-7">{{error}}</div>
</div>

data() {
    return {
        uploadErrors: [],
    }
},


validateUploadFiles(files) {

    this.uploadErrors = [];
    console.log(this.uploadErrors); // uploadErrors still contains previous items

    files.forEach( file => {
        const foundFormat = this.allowedFormats.find( format => format.mimeType === file.type );
        const isBigger = this.maxSize * 2 ** 20 < file.size;

        if( isBigger ) this.uploadErrors.push( this.$t("campaign.upload.size_limit") );
        if( !foundFormat ) this.uploadErrors.push( this.$t("campaign.upload.format") + ' ' + file.name );
    });

    console.log(this.uploadErrors);  // uploadErrors still contains previous items
}
```

What is wrong with that? I dont understand.

Comment: how is `uploadErrors ` defined?

Comment: I made an update. Look at the question.

Comment: If I try to make JSFiddle everything works fine.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/camo/rq7dntc3/7/

Comment: In fiddle you wrapped method inside `methods` in your example `validateUploadFiles` miss wrapping inside `methods`

Comment: Its because this is only a pease of code. I can not add whole file here. There is also no script tag as you can see.

Comment: @MateuszSamsel any sugestuons what happened there? Did you hear about this issue sometime?

Comment: Usually when something like that happens is a matter of reactivity in Vue. For example, you directly mutate the Array or Object in a way that Vue is not aware of (not using this.$set). However, in this example, it looks like you create a new array, so changing an array's reference for `uploadErrors` and having an empty one should clear it. Is it possible to recreate this issue in jsfiddle? Right now it looks like everything should work fine.

Comment: Yes everything looks like simple clear usecase. But it does not work. It reacts when I push new items in array but does not when I set up empty array. I really dont know how to make better example in JSFiddle.  It drives me crazy.

Comment: @Mateusz Ok I have it. The issue is caused by missing native option in Buefy upload component. It still returns all files which was selected at all https://buefy.org/documentation/upload/